# Iterating through an array of Tuples

Tags: arrays, swift

Im trying to iterate through an array of Tuples using an Index.

Heres my Array:

```
var keyValueArray = [(name: "One", value: 1), (name: "Four", value: 4), (name: "Two", value: 2) ]
```

Heres what I want to do:

```
func tupleArrayInsertionSort(var unsortedTupleArray: [(String,Int)]){
var key, y : Int
for i in 0..<unsortedTupleArray.count {
    key = unsortedTupleArray.[i]
}
```

}

However I get the error: Cannot subscript a value of type [(String,Int)]

I am just wanting to iterate through the Tuples not into them. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
key = unsortedTupleArray.[i]
```

You have a `.` between the array and the subscript. It should look like this:

```
key = unsortedTupleArray[i]
```

but that only gets you the tuple, if you want to pull out the `Int`, you need to access the second element in the tuple

```
key = unsortedTupleArray[i].1
```

Now, if you want to preserve the names of the tuples, you should keep them in the function declaration. Then you can access the value using `.value`:

```
var keyValueArray = [(name: "One", value: 1), (name: "Four", value: 4), (name: "Two", value: 2) ]

func tupleArrayInsertionSort(var unsortedTupleArray: [(name: String, value: Int)]){
    var key, y : Int
    for i in 0..<unsortedTupleArray.count {
        key = unsortedTupleArray[i].value
    }
}
```